# How to make nhibernate recognise change to a query in hbm.xml file?

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I need to make a change to an SQL query in an .hbm.xml file. I'm not that familiar with Nhibernate as yet. I've edited the file, and restarted IISExpress, which I thought would force Nhibernate to re-read the .hbm.xml file's queries (ie. upon app start), but the changes haven't been implemented.

What do I need to do to make Nhibernate recognise the .hbm.xml file edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are in general two things, which are **a must** to reload new configuration/mapping.

- redeploy the library with embeded resource into web app bin. It could seem to be automated, but if the dll *(e.g. Data.dll)* is not directly referenced by Web project... it could happen, that the old dll is used. Fix: clean solution - assure that the latest build is avaialable
- restart NHiberante Session Factory. Usually all the configuration is read only once, at the app start *(or lazily once firstly touched)*. From that moment, any changes are not refelected. Fix: after redeploy be sure you restarted web app *(its pool)*